# two buttons appearing instead of one at indexchange of dropdown

Tags: asp.net, button, iframe, html

I have a button beside a gridview in asp webpage used for printing. There is a dropdown and when I select any other option from the dropdown another print button with its iframe appears on the gridview on left positon. Both the buttons prints the content. The dropdown button loads the gridview.

Please let me know the possible solution. I have tried removing cache and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I used the asp designer for placing the button beside the gridview, but it's iframe doesn't appear with it. I just shifted the iframe with the button and the problem solved!